# How to work with XML files?

Tags: android, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, android-listview

I want to display name of continents in a ListView, let us call it **listContinents** . Upon selecting for example US, I want to display all the States there, let's call it **ListStates**. Upon selecting a particular state, I want to display all the cities in that state, let us call it **ListCity**. Upon selecting a city, I want to display some info about that city, let us call it **listCityInfo**. This is a summary for what I said above.

**Continent** >> **States** >> **Cities** >> **Info**.

How can I create one XML file containing all the information and read from it? Basically I do not know how to make it. I have the information stored in an html file, so should I convert it to an XML file. Is this the way to go?

How will I read the XML file if it contains all the information. If the XML file contains only the Continents, States, or the Cities I know how to read that, but not when all are there. How do I make it work? I don't want to create more than 500 XML files containing the cities for each state, it would be a waste of time.

Is it possible for someone to illustrate to me how this works using any example or link me to useful site?

I will appreciate it, Thank you!

Comment: Well, creating the xml should be rather trivial: e.g. every state node will have multiple city nodes; each city node will have multiple info nodes etc. Just wondering though whether a large xml file will be the way to go - it's potentially slow to do 'lookups', or expensive to keep everything in memory. I'd probably consider using a database for the content.

Comment: The size of the html file is about 56.3 KB, so is it going to be slow during parsing?  Now how would I parse the xml file and extract the information? Any links to tuts? Most tuts show by connecting to a website, which is not what I am doing.

Comment: Hard to say, as it'll depend on the complexity of the final xml structure, what parser you use (SAX vs. DOM) and the device you'll be running it on. Using something like SimpleXML or the Jackson mapper probably requires the least parsing effort from your side. I'd say any tutorial will do, as long as it explain the actual parsing logic and delegates the hard work to a background thread. Where the xml content comes from should be rather irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it.

1. Save you information into a SQlite database and put it into the asset folder.
   (But if you are familiar with webservice, I recommend you to use that. And use json because xml is a pain in the butt in Android)
2. Read it and populate to [expandable listview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).
   [Sample example](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.jp/2008/05/expandable-lists.html).

Comment: I don't know if this is the way I should go. I am leaning toward xml parser, wouldn't you think it would be more convenient ?

Comment: A database is more convenient. But you can still put it on a xml file in your asset folder if the size is not gigantic if you are comfortable with parsing xml. Performance wise, I dont recommend xml especially if dealing with a big file. There are different way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

```
  File newxmlfile = new File("/data/com.itwine/emergency.xml");

        try{
                newxmlfile.createNewFile();
        }catch(IOException e){
                Log.e("IOException", "exception in createNewFile() method");
        }
        //we have to bind the new file with a FileOutputStream
        FileOutputStream fileos = null;        
        try{
                fileos = new FileOutputStream(newxmlfile);
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                Log.e("FileNotFoundException", "can't create FileOutputStream");
        }
        //we create a XmlSerializer in order to write xml data
        XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
        try {
                //we set the FileOutputStream as output for the serializer, using UTF-8 encoding
                        serializer.setOutput(fileos, "UTF-8");
                        //Write <?xml declaration with encoding (if encoding not null) and standalone flag (if standalone not null)
                        serializer.startDocument(null, Boolean.valueOf(true));
                        //set indentation option
                        serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);
                        //start a tag called "root"
                        serializer.startTag(null, "root");
                        *//**serializer.startTag(null, "Child1");
                        serializer.endTag(null, "Child1");
                        serializer.startTag(null, "Child2");
                        serializer.attribute(null, "attribute", "value");
                        serializer.endTag(null, "Child2");*//*
                        serializer.startTag(null, "EmailId");
                        serializer.text(txtemailid.getText().toString());
                        serializer.endTag(null,"EmailId");
                        serializer.startTag(null, "PhoneNo");
                        serializer.text(txtphoneno.getText().toString());
                        serializer.endTag(null,"PhoneNo");
                        serializer.endTag(null,"root");
                        serializer.endDocument();
                        //write xml data into the FileOutputStream
                        serializer.flush();
                        //finally we close the file stream
                        fileos.close();
                       Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "xml created",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Exception","error occurred while creating xml file");
                }
```

Yes there is a way.You can use FileOutputStream to write an Xmlfile.and setting the attributes and tags using XMLserializer.Take a look i have given an example.

Comment: Sorry, downvoted for just dumping a bunch of code with absolutely zero explanation and not answering what's probably the most import part of the OP's question: `Is this the way to go?`.